# Embedding HTML code with verbatim string and not file name

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to embed HTML code in a page. I already know that the `embed` element can do this for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The embed element</h1>

<embed type="text/html" src="snippet.html"  width="500" height="200">

</body>
</html>
```

However, the embed element takes an html file as `src`. I am wondering if I could pass a verbatim string (as the HTML code) to the embed element. Is this doable with any other mechanism?

My goal is to be able to change the verbatim string dynamically with a JS code, so that the generated embedded HTML changes dynamically.

Comment: You can change any element's content with javascript. Just use a 'div' or what you like with some text, then use 'innerHtml' or 'textContent' to set it to a new string.

Comment: `document.findElementByID('myDiv').innerHTML = "<script>alert('XSS Attack!');</script>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your `html` code to the `srcdoc` of an `iframe`:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>" />
```